# Display a number with thousand separator in Indian style using NPOI

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I am using VS2008,ASP.net,C#.net.

I have a web applicaion which uses NPOI dll to export to excel 2003.
How do I display a number with thousand separator in Indian style( 12, 12,34,567.89)in the exported excel sheet? These cells with the number should applicable to apply formula (sum())

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your `CultureInfo`, it should work with the format string `"N"`.

Check your `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSizes`. If it is `{3, 2, }`, you are happy. So:

```
yourNumber.ToString("N")
```

You can give another culture if your current culture is not good, for example:

```
yourNumber.ToString("N", new CultureInfo("hi-IN"))
```

On my system, `(121234567.89).ToString("N", new CultureInfo("hi-IN"))` gives `"12,12,34,567.89"`. Those are the group sizes you desire.

As you may know, formatting can also take place like this:

```
string.Format(new CultureInfo("hi-IN"), "The number {0:N} is well formatted", yourNumber)
```

---

**Addition:** Out of curiosity, I just tested which *specific* cultures on my system use the `{3, 2, }` number group sizes, and they are:

```
hi-IN
bn-IN
pa-IN
gu-IN
or-IN
ta-IN
te-IN
kn-IN
ml-IN
as-IN
mr-IN
sa-IN
kok-IN
si-LK
ne-NP
bn-BD
en-IN
```

Comment: Hi Nielson, It will display as text when we export this to excel .So we can't apply the sum() functions in this cell.Is it possible to display as Indian number style in excel and that cell should act as a number.That means builtin functions like sum() etc can be performedon that cell

Comment: @user3253876 I am no Excel expert. Try using the `[excel]` tag (will insert that for you) in this question. Maybe you need _no_ formatting in the C# part, and only want the formatting to happen when Excel presents the numbers? I tried to google, and found [How to show Indian Currency Format in Excel?](http://chandoo.org/wp/2010/07/26/indian-currency-format-excel/).

Answer (score 1):

with NPOI try this magic to format with Indian style:

```
ICell cell = row.GetCell(0);
cell.SetCellValue(1234567.89d);
IDataFormat dataFormatCustom = workbook.CreateDataFormat();
cell.CellStyle.DataFormat = dataFormatCustom.GetFormat("[>=10000000]##\\,##\\,##\\,##0;[>=100000] ##\\,##\\,##0;##,##0.00");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
int value 773740;
Response.Write(value.ToString("N"));
//or
Response.Write(value.ToString("#,#"));
```

To format double to string with use of thousands separator use zero and comma separator before an usual float formatting pattern, e.g. pattern „0,0.0“ formats the number to use thousands separators and to have one decimal place.

```
String.Format("{0:0,0.0}", 12345.67);     // "12,345.7"
String.Format("{0:0,0}", 12345.67);       // "12,346"
```

Refer more here http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-double/

Comment: will this number 12, 12,34,567.89 display using this?

Answer (score 0):

```
'in vb.net ---
Dim xlApp As Object
Dim xlWorkBook As Object
Dim xlWorkSheet As Object

'--- Instantiate Excel and start a new workbook.
xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks
Dim xlCells As Excel.Range = Nothing
Dim rngCell As Excel.Range = Nothing
Dim lastrow As Long
lastrow = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange.Rows(xlWorkSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
xlCells = xlWorkSheet.Range("H7:O" & lastrow)   '---change according to your need
For Each rngCell In xlCells
    If IsNumeric(rngCell.Value) = True Then
        rngCell.Value = CDec(rngCell.Value)
        rngCell.NumberFormat = "[>=10000000]##\,##\,##\,##0.00;[>=100000]##\,##\,##0.00;##,##0.00"
        rngCell.Value = Trim(rngCell.Value)
    End If
Next
```